# Pipe ls ouput to scp command

Tags: linux, scp

I have the following ls command lists the first 93 files

```
ls -lrt | head -93
```

but when i try piping this to scp like

```
scp 'ls -lrt | head -93' {} test@testserver:~/DIR1/SUBDIR
```

I recieve an error saying  ls -lrt | head -93: No such file or directory

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume that you want to transfer the first 93 files to the remote system.  If so, try:

```
scp $(ls -1rt | head -93) test@testserver:~/DIR1/SUBDIR
```

`$(...)` denotes [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).  Moreover, you don't want the *long* listing from `ls`, so replace `-l` with `-1`.

Comment: This too shall work  scp ` ls -1rt | head -93 ` test@testserver:~/DIR1/SUBDIR